# Error with USB driver during suspend

Tags: usb, 20.04, suspend, xhci-hcd

When my laptop wakes up from suspend, for a moment before the login screen appears, I see a black screen with the following error printed on it:

```
kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:38:00.0: BAR 0: error updating (0x9af00000 != 0x000000)
```

Usually I see multiple messages of this kind (all messages are the same), and the more time my laptop spends in suspend mode, the more messages appear on wake up.

I know that `xhci_hcd` is a USB driver, but I did not manage to solve this problem by myself.

My laptop is Dell XPS-9500. I have Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Are these errors actually causing problems with USB ports?

Comment: No, USB ports seem to be working fine.

Comment: I get the exact same messages while entering and leaving sleep with the Dell XPS-9700 and while using Arch Linux. There are no problems that I can see either with my USB ports.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided, it appears that that message is actually a non-issue. So, the best, and easiest thing to do, would probably be to just ignore it.